# Why is my question downrated?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I've posted my first question here. It is about complexity which in my opinion falls into computer science. I can't figure out why did I get 4 downvotes and no answer.

If it does not fit here, on computer science stackexchange, then where should I ask this kind of questions?

[The question is here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34194/how-do-we-know-that-xtime-is-a-subset-of-xspace)

Answer (score 5):

Because it is off-topic. 
Please check out [the explanation of our scope](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
It also provides suggestion about other sites, e.g. [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

(All of this are already stated in the closing comment under your question by the way.)